# show an additional image if the item in the database was added 3 days ago or less using php

Tags: php

I am trying to display an addition image next to an item if it was added to the database 3 days ago or less saying "new"?

In a table called movie there is a field called moviedateadded which stores when the movie was added to the table in DATE format e.g. 2011-09-01.

I'm guessing I need to get the current date from the server, and use an if else statement to say if the moviedateadded is 3 days or less than the server time, echo out "new.jpg"?

Please confirm the best way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$date = "2011-09-01";
if( (time() - strtotime($date)) > 3*24*60*60 ){
    echo "More than three days";
}
?>
```

According to your code (edited also <= for 3 or less instead of more than 3

```
<?php 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        if( (time() - strtotime($row['moviedateadded'])) <= 3*24*60*60 ){ 
            echo "<img src='images/twit.png'/>";
        }

 ?>
<a href="movie.php?movieid=<?php echo $row['movieid']?>">
<img src="content/movie/<?php echo $row['movieimage'] ?>.jpg">
</a>

<?php 
    } 
?>
```

Comment: I have amended this to include an image instead of text however it shows 1 image no matter what the moviedateadded field is set to for that entry?    <?php
    $date = "2011-09-01";
    if( (time() - strtotime($date)) > 3*24*60*60 ){
    echo "<img src='images/twit.png'/>";
    }
    ?>

Comment: could you edit your post to show part of that code and also include a var_dump($row['moviedateadded']) or the like to see what's the value looks like.

Comment: Martin, you have to replace $date with the date fetched from the database, perhaps strtotime($row['moviedateadded '])

Comment: I am simply querying everything in the movie table using select * from movie. Then echoing a couple of fields.                                        
    <?php while($row= mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
    <?php
    $date = "2011-09-01";
    if( (time() - strtotime($date)) > 3*24*60*60 ){
    echo "<img src='images/twit.png'/>";
    }
    ?> 
    <a href="movie.php?movieid=<?php echo $row['movieid']?>">
    <img src="content/movie/<?php echo $row['movieimage'] ?>.jpg"             
    <?php } ?>

Comment: Exactly what I said on my previous example, you're not comparing the date from your database but a fixed value which is $date = "2011-09-01";
You have to remove that and use $row['moviedateadded']
Ill answer with the code because it's hard to understand on comments.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be working, please confirm the code for the $date variable?

Comment: edited my answer so you can understand what I meant, on the code you posted you where always comparing time() to "2011-09-01" which was always more than 3 days apart.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3577/discussion-between-martin-dye-and-derp)